# How to get the index of parent array

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the index of the parent array by id.

My array has an array of products which consists of the id and the amount.
I whish to change the amount of the selected product and this would work best with the id because this is a unique value.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 ) 
[1] => Array ( [0] => 36 [1] => 6 ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 10 ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 10 ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the outer array. Then you have the parent ID and nest another loop inside.

```php
$array = [
    0 => [0 => 3,  1 => 1],
    1 => [0 => 36, 1 => 1],
    2 => [0 => 4,  1 => 1],
    3 => [0 => 37, 1 => 1]
];

foreach($array as $parentId => $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        echo "ParentId: $parentId, Key: $key, Value: $value\n";
    }
}
```

Gives

```
ParentId: 0, Key: 0, Value: 3
ParentId: 0, Key: 1, Value: 1
ParentId: 1, Key: 0, Value: 36
ParentId: 1, Key: 1, Value: 1
ParentId: 2, Key: 0, Value: 4
ParentId: 2, Key: 1, Value: 1
ParentId: 3, Key: 0, Value: 37
ParentId: 3, Key: 1, Value: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the index of parent array by using `array_search()` this function basically finds the key of the value desired as

```
$data = [[3,1],[36,1],[4,1],[37,1]];
echo '<pre>';
echo array_search([3,1], $data).'<br>';
echo array_search([36,1], $data).'<br>';
echo array_search([4,1], $data).'<br>';
echo array_search([37,1], $data);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**

```
0
1
2
3
```

Comment: Cool, I did not know needle could be an array, too.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarkusZeller :)

Comment: Hey, this is a nice solution but not really bugfree for my app. I edited my question so its more clear.

Comment: @Jimmy.jolling It is not ok to change the complete meaning of the question. As both answers are correct, you should set your favourite one as correct, revert your question to the original problem and ask a new question.

Comment: Yes @Jimmy.jolling this is not right we both have answered correctly to your question asked first you cannot change the question afterwards please ask another one.